# Create single root user to access and manage all database of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, authentication, authorization, superuser

I have 22 databases on a single MongoDB instance. I came across [root](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/built-in-roles/#root) role of MongoDB authentication. I want to create a single user which can do anything to existing database as well as create new database and manage them fully. I ran the following command but it doesn't allow me to access any database except `admin`.

```
use admin
db.createUser(
{
    user: "iamroot",
    pwd: "<pa$$w0rd>",
    roles: [ "root" ]
})
```

It only stores `root` role for `admin` database only. How can I apply `root` role to all existing database as well as on new database if added? Is there only one way to supply all the DB name in `roles` array like this to achieve what I want?

```
use admin
db.createUser(
{
    user: "iamroot",
    pwd: "<pa$$w0rd>",
    roles: [ 
        { role: "root", db: "db_1" },
        { role: "root", db: "db_2" },
        { role: "root", db: "db_n" },
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to assign root for admin db explicitly I guess.
For me the following worked (am on version: 3.4.23):

```
use admin
db.createUser(
{
    user: "iamroot",
    pwd: "<pa$$w0rd>",
    roles: [ 
        { role: "root", db: "admin" }
    ]
})
```